# Find the subgraph that matches with the query graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithm, subgraph

I have an undirected graph `G`. Since `G` is a collection of vertices and edges, I would like to take it as a "database".

Now I have a query graph `H` that is **guaranteed to be a subgraph of `G`**. How may I figure out `H` corresponds to which part of `G`?

This question is different from the existing ones here, since basically I know for sure `H` is part of `G`.

Comment: Consider flagging your question to be migrated to [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Finding whether a graph is a subgraph of another graph, i.e. subgraph isomorphism problem is NP-complete. A method to go around this that many graph processing systems use is graph indexing. It reduces the number of candidate graphs that have to surpass the subgraph isomorphism test. There are many variations of index creation, there is a lot of research on this and a lot of papers available. These are some example papers I found useful:
[graph indexing: a frequent strucutre-based approach](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1007607) - this is quite an old one, but the problem is really well explained, very beneficial to read.
[GRAPES: A software for parallel searching on biological graphs](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0076911) - this is also worth to read, it really well explains the graph indexing procedure.

Comment: I wouldn't say that graph indexing is a method to go around the NP-hardness of subgraph isomorphism. What graph indexing can help with though is when one has many query graphs (H1, H2, ...) and one wants to spend upfront a lot of time and space to build up a graph index, and then solve SI(H1, G), SI(H2, G), ... quickly making use of the index.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Subgraph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem). If you do not restrict your query graph, it is NP-complete (as you can take H a Hamiltonian cycle). If the graph H is very small (fixed) you can find a copy of H in G in polynomial time (either by simple brute force, or by an algorithm mentioned in the Wikipedia page).